# Dynamic menu items from a database

Tags: asp-classic, ms-access-2007

Is it possible to load menu Url's and attributes from a database?

I am building a site that will incorporate dynamic news sections and it would be great to include new news items into the menu without having to re-edit the menu.

I am using Access and ASP.

Comment: Why Access? It's not really the most appropriate database for a website back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've currently finished an ASP - SQL2000 driven menu. I run it off one table and one query.

The table will need at the minimum: -

```
ID (INT)

label (char or varchar - the text that appears on the page)
sub (BIT or Boolean - if true then it has submenus)
level (the parent link - for submenus only)
link (char or varchar - what happens when you click!)
seq (INT - to order the menus and submenus)
```

The SQL or Query for the root menu items: -

```
SELECT [id],label,[level],sub,link FROM TOC where level=0 order by seq
```

Then: -

```
SELECT [id],label,[level],sub, [link] FROM TOC WHERE [level]<>0 order by [level],seq
```

For the submenus..

Finally the ASP (oMenuRoot is the recordset for the ROOT menus, oMenuSub is the recordset for the SUB menus: -

```
<%do until oMenuRoot.eof%>
,"<%=oMenuRoot("label")%>","<%
if oMenuRoot("sub") then
response.write "show-menu=" & oMenuRoot("id")
else
response.write Application("homePage") & "?" & oMenuRoot("link")
end if
%>",,"",1<%=vbcrlf%>
<%intRoots=intRoots+1
oMenuRoot.movenext
loop

do until oMenuSub.eof
if intOldTree<>oMenuSub("level") then
blnNewTree=true
response.write "])" & vbcrlf
else
blnNewTree=false
end if
if blnNewTree then
response.write "addmenu(menu=["""
response.write oMenuSub("level")
response.write """," & vbcrlf
response.write ",,120,1,"""",style1,,""left"",effect,,,,,,,,,,,," & vbcrlf
end if
response.write ",""" & oMenuSub("label") & ""","""
if oMenuSub("sub") then
response.write "show-menu=" & oMenuSub("id")
else
response.write Application("homePage") & "?" & oMenuSub("link")
end if
response.write """,,,1" & vbcrlf
intOldTree=oMenuSub("level")
oMenuSub.movenext
loop
response.write "])" & vbcrlf
%>
```

This is draft working model, but works without problems, you could improve by using one SQL query and writing all the output inside ASP markup.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

You could write an ASP page that generates the menu definition file (the JS file that has all of the "addmenu" lines in it). Or more precisely, that ASP file generates the text that would go in that file, but you'd include that ASP into your main ASP file.

However, If that data doesn't change too often it might still be better to have a background program generate a JS file, that is then included in your main page, as this would reduce the load on your app server(s).